# Using activemerchant with PayPal Payments Advanced

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal, activemerchant

I have a hosted web site built on Rails 2.3.14 and Ruby 1.8.7.  In order to capture shipping info so I can compute shipping charge, I provide the form for shipping address and then use a credit card processor just to handle the actual credit card entry and authorization.  PayPal's Payments Advanced does exactly what I want.  I'd really like to use the activemerchant gem but I cannot find information on which specific gateway to use or how.  There is an active_merchant discussion on github that says "This is almost an carbon copy of Payflow Link", but I cannot manage to convert that to a useful example, since every example I find passes CC info.  Can anyone point to or provide an example of this usage of activemerchant?

-Russ

Comment: dont think anyone is going to help you with that acceptance rating Russ

Comment: If you going to use paypal gateway then you can consider using [paypal-sdk-merchant](https://github.com/paypal/merchant-sdk-ruby)  gem. Samples available at [http://paypal-sdk-samples.herokuapp.com/merchant/do_direct_payment](http://paypal-sdk-samples.herokuapp.com/merchant/do_direct_payment).

Comment: Thanks siddick, that gems looks good.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: DoDirectPayment is for PayPal Payments Pro, not Payments Advanced.  Also, DDP is the "old" version of Payments Pro.  Now when you apply for Pro they'll put you in the PayFlow Pro product, so keep that in mind.  They're both $30/mo as oppose to $5/mo like Payments Advanced, too.

Answer (score 0):

Payments Advanced is basically PayFlow Link, but it uses PayPal as your merchant processor instead of a 3rd party merchant account.

As such, you'll use the same steps as PayFlow link with a few minor changes.  You can get all of the [info about Payments Advanced here](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/development-and-integration-guides#ppa).

I don't know of any specific gem already developed for it, though.

Comment: Thanks Andrew.  I don't need a specific gem so much as a working example.  But I think I can work it out from the link you provided, knowing that that's the right place to look.